# How to filter datagridview using multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a `datagridview` which gets its data from a database and three `checkBoxes` which should be used as a filter.

I want to filter the `datagridview` by checking one or more of the `checkedboxes` and should display me the selected item in the `datagridview` with it relating Amounts:

[image: datagridview]

[image: checkBoxes]

My code:

```
           if (cb11.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check an see what's in the dgv
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = " [AreaCode] = " + cb11.Text.Trim();
                datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can’t find the column", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }
```

This give me only the values for 11
How can i join the other one so the i can select multiples ?

Comment: Sounds great. what are you waiting for?

Comment: Plz Show us what you have tried ? and the problem  you are facing

Comment: Hi zohar,
I'm expecting  something like excel filtering (dynamic):
if i check 16 and  31 i expect the result in datagridview to be:
`11      5.660.596      5.849.473.      -188.877.125`
 `31      88.326.252     88.702.273    -376.021.097`

Comment: Ok. That's what I have so far and it isn't working:

       `if (cb11.Checked == true)
            {
                try
                {
             //Check an see what's in the dgv
              DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
               dv.RowFilter = " [AreaCode] = " + cb11.Text.Trim();
                    datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
            MessageBox.Show("Can’t find the column", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

            }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing code that you have tried, I'll just give an explanation of what you can try.

Assuming that you fetch the data, from the database, only once:

1. Get your data from the database and store it in a list
2. Each time you check/uncheck checkboxes

   2.1. Clear your datagridview

   2.2. Iterate through your list and populate your datagridview based on the checked checkboxes.

If you're fetching the data multiple times:

1. Each time you check/uncheck checkboxes

   1.1. Clear your datagridview

   1.2. Construct a query based on the checked checkboxes

   1.3. Query for your data, and populate your datagridview

**EDIT:**

So with the code you provided, try creating a string that you'll set to the RowFilter after evaluating all check boxes.

```
        string rowFilter = string.Empty;
        if (cb11.Checked)
        {
            rowFilter += " [AreaCode] = " + cb11.Text.Trim();
        }
        if (cb16.Checked)
        {
            if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
                rowFilter += " OR";
            rowFilter += " [AreaCode] = " + cb16.Text.Trim();
        }
        if (cb31.Checked)
        {
            if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
                rowFilter += " OR";
            rowFilter += " [AreaCode] = " + cb31.Text.Trim();
        }

        try
        {
            //Check an see what's in the dgv
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter = rowFilter;
            datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can’t find the column", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Shar1,

The filtering is only working for cb11 and if i checked the other ones they aren' filtering. And if i select two or more it only filter cb11

Comment: Can you edit your code post, so I could see what you changed in your code sample?

Comment: Thanks Shar1

I get it now. I had an  error in reasoning :)

Comment: Hi Shar1,
I'm trying to convert the code u helped me with from `checkedBoxes` to `Treeview checkboxes` but it isn't working. Can u please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string RowFilter = string.Empty;
CreateOrAppendToFilter(cb11, ref RowFilter);
CreateOrAppendToFilter(cb16, ref RowFilter);
CreateOrAppendToFilter(cb31, ref RowFilter);
  if(RowFilter.Length > 0) 
  {
     try
        {
            //Check an see what's in the dgv
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter = RowFilter;
            datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can’t find the column", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
  }

    private void CreateOrAppendToFilter(CheckBox cb, ref string RowFilter) 
    { 
        if(RowFilter.Length>0) 
        {
            RowFilter += " OR ";
        }
        RowFilter += (cb.Checked) ? string.Format("[AreaCode] = {0}", cb.Text.Trim()) : string.Empty ;
    }
```